# read JSON input in slim framework

Tags: php, json, slim

i am new to slim framework following a tutorial i managed to get post data to my API.but when i tried to send data as JSON it gives me an error.I tried to accpt JSON request as follows what is the correct syntax to achive this.i get error as Required field(s) name, email, password is missing or empty

```
$app->post('/login', function() use ($app) {
                // check for required params
                $json = $app->request->getBody();
                $data = json_decode($json, true); 
                verifyRequiredParams(array('name','email', 'password'));
```

how i can get json data from a post request in my API from an JSON array like

```
{
"name":"usertest",
"email":"xxxx@xxx.xxx",
"password":"xxxxxx"
}
```

can i use `verifyRequiredParams(array('name','email', 'password'));`  and `$name = $app->request->post('name');` if request come as a JSON.

Comment: You mean you want to transform the array to JSON?

Comment: Sorry if i have used wrong terms.my concern is if we send a JSON array of data in post method how to read it, like $email = $app->request->post('email') is it same? i think error is coming when i try to verify parameters. i'll add a sample posting array to question.

Comment: I added a solution. If it does not solves your problem, please post the content of `$data` (e.g. `print_r($data);`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read the request data you can use your `$data` property. It should be an object so you can use it like this:

```
$name = $data->name;
$email = $data->email;
```

**EDIT:**

Use `$data = json_decode($json)` instead of `$data = json_decode($json, true)` to convert the json data to object instead of an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with placing my `verifyRequiredParams` function i think.i fixed the issue from following code in case any one had same issue.

```
$app->post('/login', function() use ($app) {
            if($app->request->headers->get('Content-Type')=='application/json'){
                $json = $app->request->getBody();
                verifyRequiredParamsjson(array('email','password'),$json); 
                $data = json_decode($json); 

                // check for required params                            

                $email = $data->email;
                $password = $data->password;
            }
            else{
                // check for required params
                verifyRequiredParams(array('email', 'password'));
                // reading post params
                $email = $app->request->post('email');
                $password = $app->request->post('password');
            }

            $response = array();

            $db = new DbHandler();
            // check for correct email and password
            if ($db->checkLogin($email, $password)) {
                // get the user by email
                $user = $db->getUserByEmail($email);

                if ($user != NULL) {
                    $response["error"] = false;
                    $response['name'] = $user['name'];
                    $response['email'] = $user['email'];
                    $response['apiKey'] = $user['api_key'];
                    $response['createdAt'] = $user['created_at'];
                } else {
                    // unknown error occurred
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = "An error occurred. Please try again";
                }
            } 
            else{
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'Login failed. Incorrect credentials';
                }

            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

required parameter check,

```
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields) {
    $error = false;
    $error_fields = "";
    $request_params = array();
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;
    // Handling PUT request params
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $request_params);
    }
    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
            $error = true;
            $error_fields .= $field . ', ';
        }
    }

    if ($error) {
        // Required field(s) are missing or empty
        // echo error json and stop the app
        $response = array();
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = 'Required field(s) ' . substr($error_fields, 0, -2) . ' is missing or empty';
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
}
```